# Algorithm to identify segment chains

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of segments:

```cs
ISegment[] segments
```

defined by an interface:

```cs
public interface ISegment
{
    Point3D A { get; } // Segment start point
    Point3D B { get; } // Segment end point
}
```

which can contain instances of:

```cs
public class Line : ISegment
{
    public Point3D A { get; } // Line start point
    public Point3D B { get; } // Line end point
    /* ... Other line properties & methods ... */
}
```

or instances of:

```cs
public class Arc : ISegment
{
    public Point3D A { get; } // Arc start point
    public Point3D B { get; } // Arc end point
    /* ... Other arc properties & methods ... */
}
```

and can be represented by this image:
[image: Segments representation]

I am searching an elegant algorithm to identify them as segment chains:

```cs
ISegment[][] segmentChains
```

where the result would be:

```
[[s1, s2, s3, s4], [s5, s6], [s7], [s8, s9, s10], [s11, s12]]
```

without any order consideration.

Note:

- The input 1D array `segments` can have any order
- The output 2D array `segmentChains` can have any order
- Arc segment can have the same start and end point

Some help will be welcome!

Comment: Do you already have a non-elegant solution? If so, please post it so people can suggest improvements, or help where it's not working.

Comment: What is a "segment chain", exactly?

Comment: Start at any segment. Check all other segments, anything that has a start point equal to this segments start *or* end point is connected in a chain.

Comment: Are `Arc`s ever part of a chain? Can `Arc`s chain with `Line`s? Or other `Arc`s?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, yes. [s11, s12] in the example.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ah yes I had mistaken that for a single `Arc` for some reason.

Comment: There are other possible patterns that aren't shown, which is why there is some question about what a chain is. `I` is a single-segment chain, but what if there were another segment that shared it's endpoint? Would that, then be considered part of the chain? I assume so, but it's not described in the diagram. Also, what about multiple segments that all share the same endpoint (like a starburst). Is that a `chain`?

Comment: @EstebanVerbel, I think the question is asked as it should. It even contains a picture and it asked for algorithm, not the code.

Comment: @UmarFarooq, interesting solution, why wouldn't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an iterative approach that should work. Not sure how elegant it is, though. I prefer to use `Lists` rather than `Arrays`, because they can be expanded dynamically (no size requirement on initialization).

The method signature would look like:

```
public static List<List<ISegment>>GetSegmentChains(List<ISegment> segments)
```

Where `segments` is a list of segments, and the return value is a list of "chains", where each chain is a list of segments.

The basic idea for the method is:

1. Remove a candidate segment from the list of segments (candidates) and store it in a temporary list.
2. Store it's A and B points in another list
3. For each remaining segment that has an endpoint which matches one of the points in the list:

   - Put that segment's *other* (non-matching) point in the list
   - Store the segment along with the first one
   - Remove the segment from our candidates
4. When there are no more candidates, add our temporary list to the return value list if:

   - There is more than one item in the list (a valid chain) -OR-
   - There is one item in the list but it's endpoints are the same (a single segment circle)

Here's one way it could be done:

```
public static List<List<ISegment>>GetSegmentChains(List<ISegment> segments)
{
    // Some quick 'fail fast' validation
    var segmentChains = new List<List<ISegment>>();
    if (segments == null) return segmentChains;
    if (segments.Count == 0) return segmentChains;
    if (segments.Count == 1)
    {
        if (IsSingleSegmentChain(segments[0])) segmentChains.Add(segments);
        return segmentChains;
    }

    // Get a copy of our segments
    var candidateSegments = segments.ToList();

    // Process each one
    while (candidateSegments.Any())
    {
        // Remove the first one from the candidate list and add it to a temporary chain
        // list, and add it's endPoints to a list for comparision with other candidates
        var candidateSegment = candidateSegments.First();
        candidateSegments.Remove(candidateSegment);
        var candidateChain = new List<ISegment> { candidateSegment };
        var endPoints = new List<Point3D> {candidateSegment.A, candidateSegment.B};

        // Go through the points list, finding any candidates with a match
        while (endPoints.Any())
        {
            foreach (var endPoint in endPoints.ToList())
            {
                // Add the 'other' point to our points list from each 
                // candidate that has a match with this point
                foreach (var candidate in candidateSegments
                    .Where(c => ContainsPoint(c, endPoint)).ToList())
                {
                    endPoints.Add(GetNonMatchingPoint(candidate, endPoint));
                    candidateSegments.Remove(candidate);
                    candidateChain.Add(candidate);
                }

                // Remove this point since it's been fully processed
                endPoints.Remove(endPoint);
            }
        }

        // See if we have a chain, and if so, add it to our return list
        if (candidateChain.Count == 1 && IsSingleSegmentChain(candidateChain[0]) ||
            candidateChain.Count > 1)
        {
            segmentChains.Add(candidateChain);
        }
    }

    return segmentChains;
}
```

**Class Modifications** to include constructors and `ToString()` override

```
public interface ISegment
{
    string Name { get; }
    Point3D A { get; }
    Point3D B { get; }
}

public class Line : ISegment
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Point3D A { get; }
    public Point3D B { get; }

    public Line(string name, Point3D a, Point3D b)
    {
        Name = name;
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class Arc : ISegment
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Point3D A { get; }
    public Point3D B { get; }

    public Arc(string name, Point3D singlePoint) : this(name, singlePoint, singlePoint)
    {
    }

    public Arc(string name, Point3D a, Point3D b)
    {
        Name = name;
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

**Helper Methods** to generate the list of segments in your example, to determine if a segment is a single-segment chain, to determine if a segment contains a point, and to get the non-matching point from a segment:

```
public static List<ISegment> GenerateSegmentList()
{
    // Generate the points in the diagram
    var A = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);
    var B = new Point3D(0, 0, 1);
    var C = new Point3D(0, 0, 2);
    var D = new Point3D(0, 0, 3);
    var E = new Point3D(0, 0, 4);
    var F = new Point3D(0, 0, 5);
    var G = new Point3D(0, 0, 6);
    var H = new Point3D(0, 0, 7);
    var I = new Point3D(0, 0, 8);
    var J = new Point3D(0, 0, 9);
    var K = new Point3D(0, 1, 0);
    var L = new Point3D(0, 1, 1);
    var M = new Point3D(0, 1, 2);
    var N = new Point3D(0, 1, 3);

    // Generate the segments in the diagram
    return new List<ISegment>
    {
        new Line("s1", A, B),
        new Line("s2", B, C),
        new Line("s3", C, D),
        new Line("s4", D, E),
        new Line("s5", F, G),
        new Line("s6", G, H),
        new Arc("s7", I),
        new Line("s8", J, K),
        new Line("s9", K, L),
        new Line("s10", L, J),
        new Line("s11", M, N),
        new Arc("s12", N, M)
    };
}

public static bool IsSingleSegmentChain(ISegment segment)
{
    return segment != null && segment.A == segment.B;
}

public static bool ContainsPoint(ISegment segment, Point3D pointToMatch)
{
    return segment != null && (segment.A == pointToMatch || segment.B == pointToMatch);
}

public static Point3D GetNonMatchingPoint(ISegment segment, Point3D pointToMatch)
{
    return segment == null
        ? default(Point3D)
        : (segment.A == pointToMatch)
            ? segment.B
            : segment.A;
}
```

**Example Usage**

```
private static void Main()
{
    List<ISegment> segments = GenerateSegmentList();
    List<List<ISegment>> segmentChains = GetSegmentChains(segments);

    for(int i = 0; i < segmentChains.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Segment Chain #{i + 1}: {string.Join(" => ", segmentChains[i])}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nDone!\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think, something like following should work:

1. Put them all intio a `Dictionary` where start point is a key and a `List` of segments starting in this point is a value.
2. Put all start and end points into a dictionary, where the value is number of available end points equal to this point.
3. Take any start point which has 0 in dictionary from step 2. It can't be added to any chain. If there are no such point, take any (as there is a loop).
4. For curent point take any segment starting in it if it exists. Decrement value of available point in the dictionary.
5. If there are no suitable segment, continue from step 3.

Comment: This will work for simple cases, not for more complicated cases.  Suppose you had five line segments all intersection at same point.  You would have multiple chains.  That is why there is Dijkstra.

Comment: @jdweng, as in the question chain is represented as an array, I expect that solution with minimal number of chains (3 for your case) is correct. What kind of chains do you expect to get some other solution?

Comment: An array doesn't mean that segment[0] connects to segment[1] connects to segment[2].  The array just means segments in any order.  I expect that you have a graph(s) with the chains being a section of the graph.

Comment: @jdweng, are you talking about [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory))? As for me, it can't be named as a chain. Chain should be a path, sequence :)

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you.  I'm just saying chain/path is part of a graph.